# trying to make html box around entry fields and make it all nice

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a bunch of fields that I am trying to make a border around. I played around with some style and place `<p>` tags around my `<form>` tags but it doesn't do what I want. `<div>` tags seems to make thing complicated.

Where or how can I make it so its just a black border around these 9 fields? I am using a bit of angular as well, any tips on making it look "more professional" would be great. I am an intern at this new place and i want to turn in really good work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        p {
            width: 960px;
            border:1px solid black;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 10px;
            background: #ffffff

        }

    </style>
        <form class="form " role="form" >
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Ship To #</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-  model="shipToNumber" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Ship To Mnemonic</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="shipToMnemonic" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Ship To Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="shipToName" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Customer Order #</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="customerOrderNumber" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Load #</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="loadNumber" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Car Initials</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="carInitials" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Car #</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="carNumber" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Waybill #</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="waybill" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Carrier Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="carrierName" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: please post a jsfiddle.

Comment: Please take a look at [fieldset](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp)..

Comment: You can use the tag `<form>` to create a border -    `.form {border:1px solid #dbdbdb; }`

Comment: i couldnt hard code it like this? <form class="form " role="form" border: 1px solid: black >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

style the `.form-group` elements, or use the HTML [fieldset element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset)

http://jsbin.com/wokisutuba/edit?html,css,output

```
.form-group {
border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: without messing up anything else in this project can i make a seperate .form-group2{} ?

Comment: sure. you can make as many custom classes as you like. Just add that class to the elements, and style the class however you like. It will only affect elements the class `.form-group2` is applied to. :)

Comment: so the <form> tag will reference that .form-group method right? will a .form-group2 be called <form2> ?

Comment: got it! but there is so much room on the right side is there a way to make it so that there is an equal amount of space on all sides?

Comment: Sure. I recommend reading up on basic CSS stuff, such as `padding`, `margin`, `width`, and `height`. :)

Comment: so if i messed with those attribute im better off using percentage rather than pixels right for mobile friendly pages?

Comment: @GiovanniLuna generally speaking yes. I like to use percentages with a px min-width value so that way I can define the "smallest" it looks. But, you can also just use media queries and pixel values which is just as affective. You should read on responsive vs adaptive design. :)

Answer (score 0):

Div tags are really useful. I have to agree in the beginning we lose some time trying to figure them out :)

You could make that div which contains the columns to be the same as the form-group and add a new custom class of your own..

What I would do in your case would be something like this:

html..

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
    <div class="form-group myapp-nice-border col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
        <label>Ship To #</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-  model="shipToNumber" />
    </div>
</div>
```

css..

```
.myapp-nice-border {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Try this out and let me know in case I understood it wrong :(

Comment: alright will give this a shot also to see what it does, ty for the insight

Answer (score 0):

you have to target the inputs with the text field only so I would suggest something like that :

```
form input:not([type=submit]){
background-color: transparent !important;
color:white;
font-family: "Ek Mukta", sans-serif;
border: none;
border-radius: 0 !important;
box-shadow: none !important;
border-bottom: 2px solid white;
transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;

}
```

the important! argument is used to override bootstrap strongs properties sometimes.

Comment: Note I would not encourage the use of `!important` as it creates harder to maintain CSS. A higher specificity selector would be better.